# jQuery table generator is miss-appending <tr> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have written a little jQuery table generator with filtering. The problem is the script is creating `<tr>` and in the same time he closes `</tr>` so all the items displayed in `<td>` are outside their rows (`<tr>` tags).

It looks nice to eye, because you won't see any difference to be honest (at least in Firefox), but other functions are struggling because of this error (I am generating CSV based on this table later on and there is crucial to have good structure of `<tr>` and `<td>`).

Here is my code, the generating starts after empty line, the section starting with `$("table").empty();` (everything before this code is just formating data).

```
    $('#js_changeFilterForm').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var filters = $('#js_changeFilterForm').serialize(); //gathering filter inputs
      filters = filters.split("=on&"); //cleaning filter array          
      //Array corruption fix prototype
      var ss = [];
      $.each(filters, function(key, value){
        var lol = value;
        ss.push(lol);
      });
      ss = ss.join("=on");
      filters = ss.split("=on");
      filters.splice(-1,1);
      //End of fix prototype
      let data = <?php echo $js_result; ?>; //gathering data

      //Clear and generate new table with filtered data
      $("table").empty();
      $("table").append('<thead> <tr>');
      $.each(filters, function(filter_key, filter_value){
        $("table").append('<th>'+ filter_value +'</th>');
      });
      $("table").append('</tr></thead><tbody>');
      $.each(data["data"], function(key, value){
        $("tbody").append("<tr>");
        $.each(filters, function(filter_key, filter_value){
          $("tbody").append('<td> '+value[filter_value]+'</td>');
        });
      });
    });
```

And the result of HTML after generating table looks like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr></tr>
 </thead>
 <th> id </th>
 <th> name </th>
 <th> code </th>
 <tbody>
   <tr></tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>Hey that's me!</td>
   <tr></tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Nick</td>
   <td>Good guy</td>
 </tbody>
```

I think I am miss-understanding `$.each()` and that is why it's generating the table like this, because I am trying to use it as `foreach`.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a `<tr>` to the `<tbody>` but then adding `<td>` to the same `<tbody>`...

```
$("tbody").append("<tr>");
$.each(filters, function(filter_key, filter_value){
  $("tbody").append('<td> '+value[filter_value]+'</td>');
});
```

You need to create the `<tr>` and store it... then add the `<td>` to the `<tr>`...

```
var $td = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody"));
$.each(filters, function(filter_key, filter_value){
  $td.append('<td> '+value[filter_value]+'</td>');
});
```

Note, I'm using [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead of [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), so that it returns the new `<tr>` element

Comment: Oh I see, because I am not continuing in the new structure, thank you! That's a really dumb mistake I made there.

Comment: Not a problem, these things happen :-)